# Using URL Source instead of SD Card to load images

Tags: android, url, imageview, touch, zooming

I am working on a gallery application and I found this tutorial.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

The projects runs as a gallery application (Display images and swipe, zoom in-out and pinch capabilities)

And as you can see in the project, the images are being loaded from sd card . I have a url to my images and I want to load images from this url instead of using sd card.

All advices could be helpful. Thank you

I edited the question .

Answer (score 0):

For downloading the image from the internet create a class that extends async and takes your ImageView and a url and returns a bitmap:

something like this:

```
private class LoadImagefromUrl extends AsyncTask< Object, Void, Bitmap > {
        ImageView ivPreview = null;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground( Object... params ) {
            this.ivPreview = (ImageView) params[0];
            String url = (String) params[1];
            System.out.println(url);
            return loadBitmap( url );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( Bitmap result ) {
            super.onPostExecute( result );
            ivPreview.setImageBitmap( result );
        }
    }

    public Bitmap loadBitmap( String url ) {
        URL newurl = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            newurl = new URL( url );
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( newurl.openConnection( ).getInputStream( ) );
        } catch ( MalformedURLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {

            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

In your case i believe your touchImageView class extends ImageView so you can replace ImageView with the View Class you are using..

then from your activity that holds the view you can say:

```
new LoadImagefromUrl( ).execute( imageView, url );
```

You don't want to hold up the UI while you are downloading
hope that helps..

As for integrating a TouchImageView that allows your pinch zoom functionality take note of this class Your link included:

**TouchImageView.java**

```
package info.androidhive.imageslider.helper;


    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.graphics.PointF;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

        Matrix matrix;

        // We can be in one of these 3 states
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int DRAG = 1;
        static final int ZOOM = 2;
        int mode = NONE;

        // Remember some things for zooming
        PointF last = new PointF();
        PointF start = new PointF();
        float minScale = 1f;
        float maxScale = 3f;
        float[] m;

        int viewWidth, viewHeight;
        static final int CLICK = 3;
        float saveScale = 1f;
        protected float origWidth, origHeight;
        int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

        ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

        Context context;

        public TouchImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            sharedConstructing(context);
        }

        public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            sharedConstructing(context);
        }

        private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
            super.setClickable(true);
            this.context = context;
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
            matrix = new Matrix();
            m = new float[9];
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

            setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                    origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                    origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                    }

                    setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    invalidate();
                    return true; // indicate event was handled
                }

            });
        }

        public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
            maxScale = x;
        }

        private class ScaleListener extends
                ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                mode = ZOOM;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
                float origScale = saveScale;
                saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
                if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                    saveScale = maxScale;
                    mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
                } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                    saveScale = minScale;
                    mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
                }

                if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                        || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                            viewHeight / 2);
                else
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                            detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

                fixTrans();
                return true;
            }
        }

        void fixTrans() {
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

            float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
            float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                    * saveScale);

            if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
                matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
        }

        float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
            float minTrans, maxTrans;

            if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
                minTrans = 0;
                maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            } else {
                minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
                maxTrans = 0;
            }

            if (trans < minTrans)
                return -trans + minTrans;
            if (trans > maxTrans)
                return -trans + maxTrans;
            return 0;
        }

        float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
            if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
                return 0;
            }
            return delta;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            //
            // Rescales image on rotation
            //
            if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                    || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
                return;
            oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
            oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

            if (saveScale == 1) {
                // Fit to screen.
                float scale;

                Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
                if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                        || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                    return;
                int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

                Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

                float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
                float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
                scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
                matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

                // Center the image
                float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                        - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
                float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                        - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
                redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
                redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

                matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

                origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
                origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
            fixTrans();
        }
    }
```

You can simply create a similar class and either include it in your xml layout or attach in java.  Replace my references above to ImageView with the TouchImageView.

for more info on this consult android docs..

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response but I don't see how to integrate this class with the existing project. Can you check the link I gave and explain some other steps please.

Comment: Ok i will give it a try and if it works you will get your accept point :) Thank you any way :)

Comment: no problem.. note. the TouchImageView above has the package name of the original project, you would have your package  path there

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso library to load remote images into your TouchImageView.

```
 Picasso.with(MyActivity.this).load(urlOfImage).fit().centerInside().error(R.drawable.no_img).into(touchImageView);
```

You need to following dependency to your build.gradle file to use Picasso Library

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,hope it works

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ArrayList<String> articleList = getArticleData();

        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this,articleList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getArticleData() {
        ArrayList<String> articleList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(MyArticleData.articles));


        return articleList;
    }
}
```

**For Url**

```
public class MyArticleData {

    static String[] articles = {

            "https://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/donut.png",
            "https://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/eclair.png",
            "https://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/froyo.png",
             ----
             -----
             ------
            https://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/donut.png"
           };
}
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    public LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    View imageView;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> urls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = urls;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 30;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        //imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

        Picasso.with(context).load(data.get(position)).into(imageView);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**pager_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```